# Difficulty understanding while loop execution

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using std::cin;             // <iostream>
using std::cout;            // <iostream>
using std::endl;            // <iostream>
using std::setprecision;    // <iomanip>
using std::sort;            // <algorithm>
using std::streamsize;      // <ios>
using std::string;          // <string>
using std::vector;          // <string>


int main()
{
    cout << "Enter your homework grades : " << endl;
    double x;

    vector<double> homework;

    int count = 0;

    while(cin >> x)
    {
        homework.push_back(x);
        ++count;
        if(count == 0)
        {
            cout << "Error, enter a grade" << endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I'm wondering why my while loop wont print the message (Error, enter a grade) on the screen if the  if-statement is within the loop, and seems to only work when its placed outside after the loop executes why is this the case?

Comment: In your while loop, the if statement only executes if count = 0, which is not the case because you have ++count right before it, so you are goint to start with count = 1. You need to put that line after your if statement.

Comment: Don't worry, it will print if you input enough numbers and if your compiler supports number overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never going back to zero.

```
int count = 0;
//...  
while(cin >> x)
{
    homework.push_back(x);
    ++count;
    if(count == 0)  //count will never be zero
```